# Can convergence interval of series differ by representation?

Tags: calculus, power-series

(1)

$\begin{align}\frac{1+x}{1-x}&=(1+x)\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\space(|x|<1)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+x)x^n\space(|x|<1)\\
\end{align}$

But when $x=-1$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+x)x^n$ converges
So convergence interval is [-1,1)

(2)

$\begin{align}\frac{1+x}{1-x}&=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1} \space(|x|<1)\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n} \space(|x|<1)\\
&=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \space(|x|<1)\\
\end{align}$
So convergence interval is (-1, 1)

Series representation of (1) and (2) is different and convergence interval is different. Is this generally correct?

Comment: Clearly if you take the Taylor series at a point $a$ then you can get a series which converges in a neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, if you see them as series of functions. But you should be aware of the fact that your first series is not a power series, whereas the second one is.

Comment: To add to this, power series are unique. So yes, two different series representations of a function can have different convergence. This is part of the game that is played in the analytic continuation of the Riemann Zeta function for example. But a function cannot even have two different *power* series representations.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Presumably you mean to say that you can't have different power series of the same function centered at the same point?

Comment: Yes, I should have specified that power series representations are the same *at the same point*.